# Signature is Invalid after attaching certificate to the processed pdf document. i am unable to get if there is an issue in code or certificate

Tags: c#-4.0, itext, certificate, digital-signature, acrobat

I have a signed pdf I am attaching a certificate(.pfx) to the document through **itextsharp**. Everything in the code is tested and working fine but when I download and open the pdf in acrobat reader it says the signature is not valid I have changed preferences tried almost every setting since yesterday but there isn't any luck.

two things I noticed in certificate detail that for its "**intended**" property: **the DIGITAL signature is not mentioned whereas encrypt document etc is mentioned** is this the reason it is not validating the document for signature.
and the second thing it says: **certificate has error: not valid for usage**

code for attaching certificate;

```
 var pathCert = 
 Server.MapPath("..../App_Data/Certificates/.....sdd.pfx");

string Password = "**************";
var pass = Password.ToCharArray();

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store store =
new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store
(Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser);



store.Open(System.Security.
Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


string PfxFileName = pathCert;
string PfxPassword = Password;

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = new 


 System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
 (PfxFileName, PfxPassword, Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.
 X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);


 string SourcePdfFileName = "(Directory)/Desktop/tetsing/test.pdf";
 string DestPdfFileName = "(Directory)/Desktop/tetsing/test_Signed.pdf";
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new 
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new 
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { 
 cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.IExternalSignature externalSignature = new 
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");
 PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfFileName);
 FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(DestPdfFileName, FileMode.Create);  
 //the output pdf file
 PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, 
 '\0');
 PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = 
 pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

 signatureAppearance.Reason = "Signed Document";
 signatureAppearance.Location = "Unknown";
 signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = 
 PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
 MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, 
 chain, 
 null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

 pdfReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adobe acrobat reader is very picky on the certificate key usage and intended purpose (Key Usage and Enhanced Key Usage) and other details of the certificate. Have you tried a certificate with `Digital Signature` as key usage and `Code Signing` as intended purpose?

[Here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx) is a blog post that shows how to self sign a certificate with that properties for doing signatures if you do not have access to a **real** publicly trusted signing certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> certificate has error: not valid for usage

According to the Adobe [Digital Signatures Guide for IT](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/changes.html#id1), Adobe Acrobat accepts only

- one or more of the following Key usage values (if any)

  - nonRepudiation
  - signTransaction (11.0.09 only)
  - digitalSignature (11.0.10 and later)
- and one or more of the following Extended key usage values (if any)

  - emailProtection
  - codeSigning
  - anyExtendedKeyUsage
  - 1.2.840.113583.1.1.5 (Adobe Authentic Documents Trust)

Please check your certificate accordingly and replace it if it does not fulfill this condition.